# Failed building wheel for kivy

Tags: kivy, termux

Im trying to test my app out which i made using `Kivy` on Termux but it says Failed building wheel for kivy.

I thought other people may have problems with this too so I left an answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error was fixed after I had install the clang module.

```py
pip install clang
```

After this I had ran the following

```py
pip install kivy
```